# Can i exclude a file from a folder but not exclude files with same name from sub folder - InstallShield 2016 Dynamic Linking?

Tags: installshield

In InstallShield 2016 [Basic MSI Project] Dynamic Linking settings for a component, Can i exclude a file say with name A and not exclude the files with name A in subfolders.

Below settings, today excludes file with name A from all folders including the sub folders.

[image]

Comment: Can't you just un-check the "Include subfolders"

Answer (score 1):

No, the settings for a single dynamic file link are unable to do that. Depending on the number of subdirectories involved, you may prefer to create one dynamic link for the top-level directory, excluding the file name, and one dynamic link for each subdirectory, not excluding the file name.

(In general I prefer avoiding dynamic file links. They make it too easy to violate component rules, or drop required files, on accident.)

Comment: Amen on don't use dynamic linking.  It's a very rare situation that I use it.